# Javascript Passing value from a popup window to its parent window

Tags: javascript, parent-child, popupwindow

I'm new in javascript and I'm stuck here. 
Let's say I have a parent window and it has an input field as well as a button that opens a popup window. This popup window contains Images. I just need to copy image URL to that input in the parent window when I click on any image on the popup window.
Any help please. Thanks

Edit:

This is my javascript code on the popup window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clicked(address) {
    window.parent.document.getElementById('copy_img').value = address.src;

}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="copy_img" id="copy_img" size="133" />
<img border="0" onclick="clicked(this)" src="images/1.jpg" width="135" height="46">
<img border="0" onclick="clicked(this)" src="images/2.jpg" width="128" height="48">
<img border="0" onclick="clicked(this)" src="images/3.jpg" width="305" height="44">
```

**Parent Window HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" name="copy_img" id="copy_img" />
```

I Just Can't get it to work

Comment: I am not sure for this parent to popup relation !! But i think for this, you have to use back-end  for getting the value to your parent!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured it out
Use window.opener

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('archiveimages').value = address.src;
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user select the image from the popup, use the following statement to set the value of the input field. Assuming the id of the input field is 'myInputField'

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('myInputField').value = imargeUrl;
```

Comment: Please taka a look on the code in my original post. Thanks

Comment: @user2044626 sorry just saw ur edit, glad it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a window using:

```
window.open('http://www.website.com/popup/page?var=test','Note','width=700,height=500,top=150,left=150,scrollbars=yes'
```

Then when you click a link on the popup you can do:

```
goback('http://www.website.com/page?var=testing');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.parent.getImageURL(img.src);
```

The popup can access it parents javascript with the above method, just have a function (like getImageURL()) on the global scope and it will work

Comment: I have edited my post and I included a full code that I used. Can you please take a look at it?. Thanks